# Filling a column with similar values in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm beginner on StandardSQL

**My Table :**

[image]

I need your help to get the `transactionId` to be duplicated on each row instead of the Blank.

[image]

**My Query :**

```
SELECT
    hits.transaction.transactionId,

    ARRAY(
      SELECT DISTINCT AS STRUCT
       v2ProductName AS name,
       SPLIT(v2ProductCategory, '/')[safe_offset(0)] AS axis,
       SPLIT(v2ProductCategory, '/')[safe_offset(1)] AS category,
       SPLIT(v2ProductCategory, '/')[safe_offset(2)] AS subCategory,
       productQuantity AS quantity,
       productPrice as price,
       productSKU AS sku
      FROM
        hits.product
    )AS products,

FROM
    `dl-recommendation-engine.NDA_CHANEL_137002018.ga_sessions_*` as session, 
    UNNEST(hits) AS hits
    WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20191122' AND '20191202'
    AND
    hits.transaction.transactionId IS NOT NULL
    AND 
    (SELECT cd.value  FROM hits.customDimensions as cd WHERE cd.index = 10) = "fr_FR"
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, yes I added my code

Comment: @ThaoLy It's preferable to copy-paste your code into the question over taking screenshots.

Comment: You already *have* `transactionId` on each row. Your query generates rows where each row has transactionId and some array. The BQ GUI just formats array elements to separate rows. You probably want to join products directly in from clause, then you obtain one row per product, with transactionId from hit.

Comment: thank you all ! I got what i wanted :)

Comment: @ThaoLy . . . You should probably delete the question.

Comment: @TomášZáluský could you please post your comment as an answer so the community can find it more easily?

Comment: @JavierBóbeda since OP seems to be satisfied and not willing to close it himself, I would rather close question but I don't have enough reputation. Anyway you're welcome :-) - I copypasted it into answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already *have* `transactionId` on each row. Your query generates rows where each row has `transactionId` and some array. The BigQuery GUI just formats array elements to separate rows. You probably want to join products directly in from clause, then you obtain one row per product, with `transactionId` from `hit`.